# Clarification needed in using Ajax forms and Partial Page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am newbie to MVC and Web App.

Recently I have went through the article

*http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pmfawas/Asp-Net-mvc-how-to-post-a-collection/*

It uses the Ajax Form, to do the partial update towards a particular region alone..

But I have a doubt in that example...

I have seen the partial Page inside the Div with Id "AllTweets"....

```
<div id="AllTweets">
@Html.Partial("_AllTweets", Model) ***** (XXX)
</div>
```

And also in the controller action,

```
try
{
viewModel.Tweets.Add(viewModel.Tweet);
return PartialView("_AllTweets", viewModel); **** (YYYYY)
}
```

Now my question is,

They are returning the partial view along with the data from the action in the controller.

Whatever the data returned from the controller, the engine will place that data, inside the target div with id "AllTweets"...

But still, why I have to have the statement, @Html.Partial("_AllTweets", Model) inside the Div, since already I am returning the data from the controller...

And also in some of the examples, i have seen the same kind of the code..

But, even if I have removed the code "@Html.Partial("_AllTweets", Model)" inside the div, the code still works fine, and without any problem and i can able to post the data to the action in the controller.

I got totally stuck at this point.

May I kindly know, what is the reason behind it and why so.... So I can understand it more better.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, even if I have removed the code `@Html.Partial("_AllTweets",
>   Model)` inside the div, the code still works fine, and without any
>   problem and i can able to post the data to the action in the
>   controller.

Yes it will work fine. The `Html.Partial("_AllTweets",Model)` renders the partial with the specified model on every page load. After page is loaded, then ajax is used to fill the div with id `AllTweets`.

`Html.Partial("_AllTweets",Model)` is usefull when you want to display, for example, already saved tweets from your database to user when the page first loads. And then ajax takes care of later updates.